# bindfs has started requiring sudo. How can I change it back?

Tags: sudo, osxfuse

For the projects I'm working on, I need to symlink a bunch of directories from multiple places on the same drive. I'm doing this via **osxfuse and bindfs**, and I have a startup script on my Mac that automatically runs all of my mount scripts to symlink those directories.

This has been working great, but last week, in the process of installing Octave via brew my osxfuse and bindfs were updated, and now it will only work if I run it with sudo. If I try to run it without sudo, I get:

```
mount_osxfuse: failed to mount [path to mount point]@/dev/osxfuse12: Operation not permitted
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this so that I don't need to sudo it?

Comment: Ever figure this out?